# ascending order of duplicates with user input in java

Tags: java, sorting

1. ask user to input how many numbers
2. input numbers
3. output duplicate
4. But how can i input the duplicates into ascending order
5. [image]
   ==========================================================================================

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class newclass 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Terms:");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers:");
        List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int t = input.nextInt();
            number.add(t);
        }

        System.out.println("Duplicates: ");
        int k = number.size();
        int l = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < k-1; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < number.size(); j++) 
            {
                if (number.get(i) == (number.get(j))) 
                {
                    l++;
                    number.remove(j);
                }             
            }
            if(l>0)
            {
                System.out.print(" " + number.get(i) );
                l=0;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using Set.add() which returns false if the element was already in the set. method as below

```
public static <T> Set<T> findDuplicateBySetAdd(List<T> list) {

            Set<T> items = new HashSet<>();
            return list.stream()
                    .filter(n -> !items.add(n)) 
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        }
```

pass your list to abovemethod, it will return duplicates in ascending order :
**[5, 9]**

```
System.out.println(findDuplicateBySetAdd(number));
```

Comment: so how would I incorporate it to the code I really dont know how

Comment: It's in answer , call above method to find duplicate by passing list